# Generate JavaScript file with Java Spring Boot

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot

I have to generate JavaScript file with Java Spring Boot and return it as function return type. Something like this:

```
public WhatShouldBeReturnType generateJs() {
        
   WhatShouldBeReturnType jsFile = generate();
   return jsFile;
}
```

Where jsFile should be something like

```
<script>
   // all the other syntax from JavaScript
</script>
```

What is the best way to do this kind of functionality, and is it even possible to accomplish something like this?

Thanks.

Comment: Does `WhatShouldBeReturnType` mean you want suggestions for a Java class there? How will you generate the JavaScript code? The whole concept looks like a big code smell to me. (not to say "stinks" ;-) Is a static resource that you serve not enough? Please describe the actual problem to be solved with that a bit better.

Comment: I don't want a concert custom example (maybe if there is some existing one from some library) for WhatShouldBeReturnType. Just asking what are options for returning dynamically generated JavaScript code and what is the best way to generate JavaSctipt code with Java. Maybe some libraries, best practices, something like that.

Comment: What is your  ultimate goal? What are you using this generated JS code for? As @cyberbrain mentions, this information goes to the ultimate problem that you're trying to solve, since this question may be an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) question.

Comment: Ok, first scenario would be, is it possible to have endpoint so when I call it I get to download JS file?
If that is not possible than I would like to return this dynamically generated JS file in any other way, maybe as String, Text or some other type which is suitable for this case.

Comment: Why do you need to generate the whole JavaScript code dynamically on the server, instead of having a static JavaScript file that just downloads data dynamically from the server (e.g. as JSON format) and processes it? It is really not advisable to generate code dynamically - you can hardly ever test it properly for a stable result.